# Using infinitive instead of perfect infinitive

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitives, perfect-aspect

[Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked) I see below sentence:

> We hope to have finished the building works by the end of March

My question is if I write this sentence using infinitive instead of the perfect infinitive then will it be wrong? And why?

> We hope to finish the building works by the end of March

UPDATE 1: I want to know from strict grammar point of view.

Comment: They are both OK with a slight difference, possibly, with the distinction that in the first sentence, when the end of March comes, the building works will have been completed some time before then. In the second sentence, the end of March seems to be a deadline.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, thanks. I should have mentioned that I want to know the grammar point of view - so second sentence is also grammatically correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strict grammar point of view, neither is wrong.  They're both grammatical.